# Print JSON output into table - PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I need to print `JSON` output in the table

```
{
  "response_code":200,
  "pnr":"6642876935",
  "train_num":"12792",
  "train_name":"PNBE SC EXP",
  "doj":" 6- 7-2015",
  "from_station":
       {
         "code":"PNBE"
       },
  "to_station":
      {
         "code":"SC"
      },
  "reservation_upto":
      {
         "code":"SC"
       },
  "boarding_point":
       {
          "code":"PNBE"
       },
   "class":"SL",
   "no_of_passengers":"1",
   "chart_prepared":"N",
  "passengers":[
     { 
        "sr":"1",
        "booking_status":"W\/L   43,
        GNWL","current_status":
        "RAC   19"
     }
  ],
  "noms":1,
  "error":null
}
```

Thank You,

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show us what you tried and you best effort to solve your problem yourself. This is somewhat a very simple logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your json has multiple nested arrays you need to iterate over those aswell. So we check if our value is an array if so we use an other foreach loop.

```
<?php
$json = '{"response_code":200,"pnr":"6642876935","train_num":"12792","train_name":"PNBE SC EXP    ","doj":" 6- 7-2015","from_station":{"code":"PNBE"},"to_station":{"code":"SC"},"reservation_upto":{"code":"SC"},"boarding_point":{"code":"PNBE"},"class":"SL","no_of_passengers":"1","chart_prepared":"N","passengers":[{"sr":"1","booking_status":"W\/L   43,GNWL","current_status":"RAC   19"}],"noms":1,"error":null}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
?>

<table> 
      <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($data as $key => $value){ 

            if(is_array($value)){
                  foreach($value as $element){  
                        if(is_array($element)){
                              foreach($element as $key2 => $child){?>

                                    <tr>
                                          <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $key2; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $child; ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                  <?php       }
                        } else { ?>

                  <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $element; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                  </tr>

                  <?php }
                  }

            } else {   ?>

            <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                  <td></td>
            </tr>

      <?php }
      } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '{"response_code":200,"pnr":"6642876935","train_num":"12792","train_name":"PNBE SC EXP    ","doj":" 6- 7-2015","from_station":{"code":"PNBE"},"to_station":{"code":"SC"},"reservation_upto":{"code":"SC"},"boarding_point":{"code":"PNBE"},"class":"SL","no_of_passengers":"1","chart_prepared":"N","passengers":[{"sr":"1","booking_status":"W\/L   43,GNWL","current_status":"RAC   19"}],"noms":1,"error":null}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $value) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $key; ?></td>
        <td><?= $value; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```